# Why does my PC keep crashing?

Tags: graphics-card, crash, gpu

Home build gaming PC -black screens, blue + red screen of death, freezing, game crashes: Sounds like my PC is totally non functioning but it is! I really need your help figuring out the problem.

I built it 3 years ago with Radeon HD 7970 GPU - always had problems with intermittent game crashes and browsers closing down when surfing the net etc.  Thought it was the GPU, got in touch with ASUS followed all of their troubleshooting plus many others online but nothing worked.  Came to the conclusion it was a defective GPU so upgraded to Sapphire RX 480 a few weeks ago but problems are ongoing making it unlikely to be the GPU.  The crashes seem to be worse with high spec tasks like playing games (Witcher 3) - this may or may not be accurate - perhaps I'm more aware of it because it's so annoying being kicked out of the game multiple times in a row.

With the old GPU I used to get a "display driver error" pop up.  With the new GPU games or the internet still close down but there is no display driver error.

The DELL U2515H monitor is also new - could that be responsible for the new black screens? They occur intermittently for 1-2 seconds and then the picture is back to normal and I can continue what I was doing.

I have tried the GPU in both available PCIe slots with no change

Memtest 10 passes 0 errors

I've uninstalled, reinstalled all the drivers/Windows 10 (this problem still occured on Windows 8 prior to upgrade)

I've made sure to disable multi-screen + internal graphics in BIOS.  Running the build just with internal graphics seems to run smoothly but I'm unable to play games etc due to the spec.

Blue Screen of death errors:
PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA
NTFS.sys failed
DRIVER IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL
rtwlane_13.sys failed
BAD POOL CALLER

Spec:
Operating System
    Windows 10 Home 64-bit
CPU
    Intel Core i5 3570K @ 3.40GHz   34 °C
    Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology
RAM
    16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 666MHz (9-9-9-24)
Motherboard
    ASRock Z77 Extreme4 (CPUSocket) 36 °C
Graphics
    DELL U2515H (2560x1440@60Hz)
    4096MB ATI Radeon RX 480 Graphics (Sapphire/PCPartner)  48 °C
PSU
         XFX 650W 80+ Bronze Certified Semi-Modular ATX Power Supply
Storage
    238GB PLEXTOR PX-256M5S (SSD)
    1863GB Western Digital WDC WD2003FYYS-02W0B1 (SATA)
    894GB SanDisk Ultra II 960GB (SSD)  25 °C

Really appreciate your help

**Edit**
Have previously updated BIOS - just checked and still on most recent version.

Comment: "I used to get a "display driver error" pop up" did you try updating the Drivers? you didn't mention if you tried that or not

Comment: PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA suggests a RAM issue. If Memtest shows the RAM is fine, my best guess is a motherboard fault, especially if you have IRQ problems.

Comment: You should use windbg to determine the actual driver causing your problems.  There is an existing question and answer on this site that explains how to use windbg.

Comment: share the dmp files

Comment: Posted up above that I updated all GPU drivers/uninstalled and reinstalled them.

@Ramhound - I'm downloading the tools and found the how to.  Can you explain to me what "make certain that your pagefile still resides on the system partition" means in terms of ensuring Windows can save the debug files? (http://forums.majorgeeks.com/index.php?threads/how-to-debug-memory-dumps-figure-out-what-is-causing-a-bsod.35246/)

Comment: @magicandre1981 can you tell me how to do that please? I searched before and it's beyond my understanding.

Thanks everyone

Comment: "make certain that your pagefile still resides on the system partition" - This means the page file is located on the same partition as Windows.

Comment: @magicandre1981

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-VK-pfBB9zGZ3hHVVV6ZENQWWs?usp=sharing

Dumps attached

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry not familiar with Windbg - looks like I should have cleared the screen prior to opening another dmp file but couldn't work out how to.

Comment: Had similar issues with my son's PC... tried everything... Finally changed out power supply and the problems went away, the unit we had was easily large enough (Thermaltake 650w)but must have been supplying dirty power, once we replaced it with a new EVGA 650w, problems were gone. Just a thought.

Comment: share the real dmp files, no txt files

Comment: @magicandre1981 uploaded - 1st time doing this, sorry.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for your comment - It would be annoying to have to replace the PSU but I wouldn't mind too much if I knew it was definitely the issue!  No way of knowing without changing it?

Comment: @Lalsa87 Unfortunately, no... We had the advantage of I ordered a new PS for something else but before it went in that box we just threw it in his PC on a whim to test and BAM, problems gone.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dumps shows a memory corruption:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PFN_LIST_CORRUPT (4e)
Typically caused by drivers passing bad memory descriptor lists (ie: calling
MmUnlockPages twice with the same list, etc).  If a kernel debugger is
available get the stack trace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000099, A PTE or PFN is corrupt
Arg2: 0000000000397f35, page frame number
Arg3: 0000000000000002, current page state
Arg4: 0400039000397f36, 0

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.321 (rs1_release_inmarket.161004-2338)

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To Be Filled By O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  P2.90

BIOS_DATE:  07/11/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASRock

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z77 Extreme4

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MiDeleteSystemPagableVm
03 nt!MiFreePagedPoolPages
04 nt!ExFreeLargePool
05 nt!ExFreePoolWithTag
06 dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::RecordVaPagingHistoryMapGpuVa
07 dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::VidMmMapGpuVirtualAddressInternal
08 dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::VidMmMapGpuVirtualAddress
09 dxgkrnl!DxgkMapGpuVirtualAddress
0a nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
0b 0x0

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff8033b3f68d1-fffff8033b3f68d2  2 bytes - nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+23441
    [ 80 fa:00 f1 ]
2 errors : !nt (fffff8033b3f68d1-fffff8033b3f68d2)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE
```

The kernel `ntoskrnl.exe` has 2 errors that cause the crash. Even if you tested the RAM there could be still an issue with your Corsair Vengeance ( CML16GX3M2A1600C9) RAM. Test it with a different memtest tool like memtest86+.

The Command Rate (CR) of 1

[image]

is also problematic in some cases. Set the Command Rate in the BIOS/UEFI to 2.

Comment: I used Memtest86+ - I uploaded a pic of it after 10 passes to https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-VK-pfBB9zGZ3hHVVV6ZENQWWs?usp=sharing

Could it come up with memory corrupt and it actually be a different problem or is that really unlikley?

Comment: post pictures of CPU-Z from Memory/SPD tab, maybe the timings are wrong

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-VK-pfBB9zGZ3hHVVV6ZENQWWs 

@magicandre1981

Comment: ok, change the Command Rate (CR) from 1 to 2. CR of 1 can cause issues

Comment: can you tell me how to do that please? I can't find a clear explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: in the BIOS/UEFI there should be an option to manually set the RAM timings and here set the Command Rate from 1 to 2.

Comment: if you look on the zip file BIOS you can see the pictures - when I go into dram configuration I can't change the command rate from 1 to 2 as it's locked on auto.  I have no experience with this so I don't feel confident to change it without some help!

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-VK-pfBB9zGZ3hHVVV6ZENQWWs?usp=sharing

Comment: at "load XMP setting" select manual/disabled and use a normal profile, not the OC XMP profile. maybe you now get an option to change CR

Comment: XMP 1.3 Profile1 is the only thing that comes up under "load XMP setting" and even on that I can't change command rate from auto.

Comment: I don't know you BIOS/UEFI. look in the manual how to change the settings

Comment: I've already looked.  It isn't specific.

Comment: I looked in the PDF (ftp://europe.asrock.com/Manual/Z77%20Extreme4.pdf) and on site 57 it shows that you can change CR from Auto to Manual setting

Comment: That's what I mean - it doesn't work.  It's not possible to just click on it and change it.  You can't edit it.

Comment: for XMP profile, select "default" and not "Auto"

Comment: XMP 1.3 Profile1 is the only thing that comes up under "load XMP setting" and even on that I can't change command rate from auto. – Lalsa87 Nov 1 at 20:57

Comment: do you have a friend who also uses DDR3 RAM in his PC? Can you test his RAM and look if the PC is stable or not?

Comment: have you tried other (non highend) RAM that doesn't have a XMP profile?